# I'm rigging a rocket landing leg and something has happened

Tags: modeling, animation, armature

The Armature deforms the mesh in a weird way. Does anyone have a fix?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I control-z-ed the armature so it won’t be the same but it will still glitch out

Comment: I have the blend file

Comment: Wait i dont think itll work because the blend file cant be opened, this might be because i got blender from steam and not the official website

Comment: I can't see any link to your file, please use another platform if blend-exchange doesn't work

Comment: Oh I got confused. I tried dragging into the post itself

Comment: I added the .blend file

Comment: What do you mean by "weird way", for example you need to parent the object called Landing Leg Part 2 1 to the bone called Bone.003

Comment: When i move the bone it deforms the mesh in strange ways like in the image above. And when I move a parent bone it just completely moves the part

Comment: yes the first bone deforms the mesh, you should choose a method to rig: either you parent with an Armature modifier, in that case you can join all the mesh into one object, parent With Empty Groups, then assign the vertices to the groups they should be part of... Or you directly parent to bones: in that case, keep the objects separate, shift select the armature, switch it to Pose mode, select the bone and Ctrl P > Bone

Comment: Alright ill try those

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see if you select a vertex of this mesh, it is not only part of the vertex group called *Bone* but also part of *Bone.001*, so it will also be deformed by *Bone.001*. You must have parented *With Automatic Weights*, which is not a good idea for this kind of object (machine, robot, manufactured object, non-organic object):

[image]

You should choose another method to rig: either you parent with an *Armature* modifier, in that case you can join all the meshes into one object, parent *With Empty Groups*, then assign the vertices to the groups they should be part of... Or you directly parent to bones: in that case, keep the objects separate, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the bone and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*.

Also don't forget to remove the *Armature* modifier for some of the objects you've parented.